# How to specify main class in assembly plugin if it is in a child module?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a parent aggregator project A with three modules X, Y and Z. Now my X project is also dependent on a different project P and P is dependent on Q project.

I want to make an executable fat-jar using maven-assembly-plugin.
currently my Z project contains the class with main method.

but I am facing class not found Exception.

This is my A POM.

```
<groupId>A</groupId>
<artifactId>A/artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<modules>
    <module>X/module>
    <module>Y</module>
    <module>Z</module>
</modules>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.from.Z.class.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> 
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but I would expect this to work. Have you declared a dependency on the Z module in A's pom? I also suggest to split out the `modules` part into a separate (aggregator) pom.

Comment: the problem was that plugin was in A pom which I moved into Z pom, the project which contains the actual main class and it worked like a charm.